# Importing MySQL structure into live SQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I have a client with a big database. I took their existing site and created a development site. I took a copy of their existing database and made multiple name changes. By name changes, I mean changing the column names, not the the field type, no adding primary/foreign keys etc. With the new changes, is it possible to import and update the column names? I'm using PHPmyAdmin.

Example structure for one of my tables.

old:

```
Column  Type            Null    Default
form    varchar(5000)    No 
date    datetime         No
```

New one to update:

```
Column      Type          Null  Default
ind_Form    varchar(5000)  No   
ind_Date    datetime       No   
bus_ID      int(11)        No
```

Is this something I can do easily with phpmyadmins import functionality? Or is this something that where I have to change the column names manually? Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You could import the file into a new table, then once the import is done just change the table names. But something you should probably consider -- is there any code anywhere tied to the column names?

Comment: @Samsquanch  I was thinking of creating a third database and merging the 2 together. The live one has crucial data which is needed. The development one has the name changes to make it more efficient. and I have updated a LOT of code to comply with the changes done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest and most consistent way I think would be creating a script to do it.

I would create another copy of the live database and start writing a script using `ALTER TABLE` statements to make the necessary changes to the database so that it matches the new schema you are trying to emulate.

Get it perfect using copies of the live database so you can be sure it will work correctly, and then run it on the live database.

Comment: Seller I think you're onto something. I plan to take a copy of the live database, make changes, thoroughly test and once ok, make it live. I think the ALTER TABLE seems to be the only way to go at this stage. Didn't even think of that. Thanks heaps for your input! Greatly appreciated